# Can't connect to local Cassandra single node cluster using java driver on RedHat Linux

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to deploy my application to the server (RedHat Linux 6.5). Cassandra which is one node cluster and java application should be on the same server. I have the problem to connect java client with cassandra as it always fires exception NoHostAvailable:

> 16:03:55,274 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@25a65b77 - Registering
>   current configuration as safe fallback point SLF4J: Actual binding is
>   of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 13.512
>   sec <<< FAILURE! - in
>   org.au.morph.bigdata.offline.cassandra.SimpleConnectorTest
>   testConnection(org.au.morph.bigdata.offline.cassandra.SimpleConnectorTest)
>   Time elapsed: 13.511 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra
>   timeout during read query at consistency ONE (1 responses were
>   required but only 0 replica responded)))
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1414)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:393)
>           at org.au.morph.bigdata.offline.cassandra.SimpleClientImpl.connect(SimpleClientImpl.java:65)
>           at org.au.morph.bigdata.offline.cassandra.SimpleClientImpl.(SimpleClientImpl.java:25)
>           at org.au.morph.bigdata.offline.cassandra.SimpleConnectorTest.testConnection(SimpleConnectorTest.java:22)
>
> Results :
>
> Tests in error:   SimpleConnectorTest.testConnection:22 »
>   NoHostAvailable All host(s) tried for ...

This works fine if I'm running it on the local Ubuntu machine. I also tried to connect my local application with remote Cassandra DB on Amazon EC2 instance, or with local Cassandra instance, and everything was working fine. However, same application with same cassandra yaml settings on the RedHat server won't connect in local mode. I can connect using cqlsh however, and I telnet on 9042, so I don't think there is something blocking port.

I tried to run with different versions of Cassandra (Apache Cassandra 3.3 and 3.7 and DataStax Distribution 3.7). Since my RedHat instance doesn't have access to yum repositories, I was using binary tarball distribution.

My cassandra.yaml settings are as follows, but I also tried different alternative of these settings and nothing helped:

```
listen_address: 127.0.0.1  
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042 
start_rpc: true 
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
```

I hope somebody could give me an idea how to investigate this issue.